# How to expire password reset token after password changed?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I set up a password reset functional in Django. I wonder how to expire password reset URL​ after it was used to reset password

Comment: [this module might be relevant](https://pypi.org/project/django-expiring-token/), depending on how you're implementing the token

Comment: I am using default token generator in Django @GreenCloakGuy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Token is generated in as auto destroyed, take a look to `_make_hash_value` on [django auth tokens](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/tokens.py), I copy here code comments:

> Hash the user's primary key and some user state that's sure to change
>           after a password reset to produce a token that invalidated when it's
>           used:
>
> 1. The password field will change upon a password reset (even if the same password is chosen, due to password salting).
> 2. The last_login field will usually be updated very shortly after a password reset.
>          Failing those things, `settings.PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT_DAYS` eventually
>          invalidates the token.
>          Running this data through `salted_hmac()` prevents password cracking
>          attempts using the reset token, provided the secret isn't compromised.